# Storing array in a c# data structure so it has behaves like a value

Tags: c#, arrays

The following code is designed so that if I change the array assigned to one node it will not affect the other node.

My question is: Is there a more "idiomatic" way to accomplish this?

```
void Main()
{
    var arr = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };

    var node1 = new Node();
    node1.Children = arr;

    var node2 = new Node();
    node2.Children = arr;

    node1.Children[0] = 9; // node2 SHOULD NOT be affected by this

    node1.Dump();
    node2.Dump();
}

class Node
{
    private int[] children;

    public int[] Children 
    { 
        get { return children; } 
        set 
        { 
            children = new int[value.Length];
            value.CopyTo(children, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to expose array? Consider `List` or some other collection... or even `IEnumerable`. Arrays are very hard to keep track of because you can modify values inside existing array. Your sample look like you trying to build immutable tree - exposing array not going to cut it.

Comment: I would not recommend *that* particular approach. Think of the principle of least surprise. I would find it *very* surprising to see the code in Main *not* result in the the first element of the array in each instance of Node having 9 as a value. I might elect to just fully encapsulate the array and expose mutators as methods.

Comment: Is the point that a `Node` has a _reference_ to an existing "template" for as long as possible, and then creates a _copy_ only when it has to?  Eg for memory purposes?  I'd at least create a property on the `Node` that indicates if the underlying storage is _the_ template or not eg `IsStillUsingTemplate` (would need to be set `FALSE` at your `Children` `set`). And if practical, I'd create a method to get the 'augmented' storage, so the caller must do this explicitly after testing `IsStillUsingTemplate` (but that may break what you're trying to do if it needs to be transparent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this **[EDITED]**:

```
class Node
{
    private int[] _children;

    public Node(int[] children)
    {
       this._children = (int[])children.Clone();//HERE IS THE IDEA YOU ARE LOOKING FOR
    }

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { return this._children[index]; }
        set { this._children[index] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: +0: Clone is probably better (at least shorter) way of copying an array... Also I'd simply use `value.ToArray();`... But exposing array as array in `get` does not look like good suggestion (even if OP's sample shows it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. if only C# let you overload the assignment operator it would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off changing the array object copy semantics rather than adding features to the Node class to support this. Fortunately there is already a class with the semantics you are looking for: List.

This simplifies the Node class:

```
class Node
{
    public List<int> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The result:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    var node1 = new Node
    {
        Children = new List<int>(arr)
    };

    var node2 = new Node
    {
        Children = new List<int>(node1.Children)
    };

    node1.Children[0] = 9; // node2 SHOULD NOT be affected by this

    Console.WriteLine("First element node1:{0}, first element node2:{1}",
        node1.Children[0], node2.Children[0]);            
}
```

Comment: +0. I don't yet see how this approach is better than something simple like `public readonly List<int> Children = new List<int>();`... plus it is still unclear why OP needs an array to be exposed...

Comment: Doah! Of course you are right. I've changed my answer. I don't agree that exposing an array is bad practice per se, but clearly it's not right for this situation.

Comment: The context of my question is that I was trying to make a node data structure that essentially had value semantics (every reference pointing to a fresh copy). I kind of hit a dead end when I realized there are no copy constructors.